# How to update an entry in boltdb using python3.6

Tags: python-3.6, boltdb

I want to update boltdb entry using python. What is the python module available for it?

I can see different drivers for boltdb like, 
neobolt, bolt-python.

I did not get proper document about it.
I want code sample for update operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`qingyunha/boltdb`](https://github.com/qingyunha/boltdb) for example you can refer [here](https://github.com/qingyunha/boltdb/blob/main/tests/test_bucket.py) but it is not updated since 11 Oct 2020

For issue there are as of now none according to [`synk.io`](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/boltdb)

For [`neobolt`](https://github.com/neo4j-drivers/neobolt) you can check the test directory [`here`](https://github.com/neo4j-drivers/neobolt/tree/4.0/test/unit) which contain sample code on how to use the library